# Docker-compose starts springboot and mysql, springboot can't connect mysql service

Tags: docker-compose

I don't know how to configure the network property in the docker-compose.yml file,After using docker-compose up, the project runs, but can't connect to the database, look at other people's configuration,Added a links tag, but there will be an error message,sequence entries are not allowed here.
springboot,msyql5.7
dockercompose.yml

```
version : '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql-compose
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: aurora1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456789
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    networks:
      - spring-demo-network
    ports:
      - "6665:3306"
    restart: always
    command: [
      '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
      '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      '--default-time-zone=+8:00'
    ]


  app:
    container_name: backend-compose
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/vol/development
    ports:
      - "8088:8088" 
    networks:
      - spring-demo-network   
    depends_on:
      - mysql
networks:
  spring-demo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Configuration in the springboot project :

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aurora?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: 123456789
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver



backend-compose | 19-06-07 08:09:02.165 [main] WARN  :  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init> - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
backend-compose | 19-06-07 08:09:03.324 [main] ERROR :  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
backend-compose | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
backend-compose | 
backend-compose | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
backend-compose |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
backend-compose |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
backend-compose |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
backend-compose |   at com.aurora.backend.Application.main(Application.java:19)
backend-compose |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
backend-compose |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
backend-compose |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
backend-compose |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
backend-compose |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
backend-compose | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
backend-compose |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right the configuration you posted under

> Configuration in the springboot project

is inside your `backend-compose` container and you are trying to connect to the mysql database (which is located inside the `mysql-compose` container) from within the `backend-compose` container? Then you have to connect to `mysql` instead of `localhost` so that your datasource url looks like:

`jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/aurora?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC`

If you are instead trying to connect to the mysql database from your **host** (instead of from within the container) then you might use `localhost`, but then you have to use port 6665 as you configured the mysql container to forward requests from the host (the system where your containers are running on) port 6665 to the container port 3306 so that your jdbc url would look like:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:6665/aurora?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC`

Comment: @condinghaus   What I want is a connection between two containers, a mirror of   jar files,mysql

Comment: @anewspringboot so if you want to connect to the database running in the `mysql` container from within the `backend-compose` container then my first suggested solution should work for you. Did you give it a try? Is it working? Or do I misunderstand what you want? Then please explain what's the difference to my suggestion.

Comment: @condinghaus it's not work,Still the same error message

Comment: Are you able to share your Dockerfile from backend-compose?

Comment: FROM aurorasystem/openjdk-zeromq:latest
MAINTAINER Aurora System <it@aurora-system.com>


VOLUME /tmp
COPY backend-2.0.0.jar  app.jar
RUN bash -c "touch /app.jar"

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]